# How to generate client certificate on Amazon EC2 for use in iOS App

Tags: ios, ssl, amazon-ec2, client-certificates

We have SSL certificate from GoDaddy loaded on our AWS Load balancer. We want to initiate HTTPS communication from our iOS App to our server on EC2. For this purpose we need to understand how to generate the client certificate? We are struggling to understand what are the steps needed.

Comment: The first issue you'll need to handle is that ELB, in https mode, doesn't support client certificates -- there's no mechanism for communicating trust, or passing the cert info to your app server.  Your purchased SSL cert has to be installed on your instances, instead, and the ELB must be in transparent TCP mode without SSL on the ELB (the app servers have to manage it).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael-sqlbot